# How to control Div properties through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to work with a web design application that uses absolute positioning, I need to create a way in which the font size for say the paragraph can be increased for accessibility purposes. I can figure this bit out, but the part I am lost at is trying to understand how to change the properties (height, padding, margins) of the Divs so the text fits and the Divs do not overlap each other. I can set height to auto, but I can't figure out how to prevent the two Div from maintain space between each other, and how I could apply this to other objects like images.

Any help would be great.

Edit: I have added a screenshot below with two basic div both the same except the bottom one has a top-margin of 15% applied, which works for large fonts but breakdown for smaller fonts.

[image]

Comment: I haven't attached code as I haven;t written any because I don't understand the logic, it's that logic that I am asking about.

Comment: @Prashant but if the width of the first div is 500px setting the margin-left of the second div (assuming they are side by side) will make the margin-left 500px and the gap between the two large?

Comment: @prashant i tried using % but that didn't work when you reduce the size of the font the gap is too large, as % relates to the width of the containing Div rather than the two divs (i.e. the page width of 980px)

Comment: @prashant The whole point is to be able to change the font size programmatically and maintain the layout in an absolute position environment.

Comment: Hey you can remove position:absolute; because this is the one that is the cause of overlapping then you can use width:auto; & now you can give margin-top to second div to maintain them on a fixed distance..

Answer (score 0):

If you place every element inside `div` tags, they will be considered as block-tags, and should not overlap each other. Then you can use javascript to change their attributes.

If you encounter some problem, maybe you could post it here with some screen, and some HTML/CSS code so we can help you more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the divs to auto in CSS. You can then access the divs' height and position with .offsetHeight and .offsetTop respectively, and adjust their positions every time you change the font size. Something like:

```
function adjust () {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 1; i < divs.length; i++)
        divs[i].style.top = divs[i - 1].offsetHeight + divs[i - 1].offsetTop + "px";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/megapop/judyc/3/